# Overlapping table td elements using E-shopper template

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using this template for my little project and I have been stuck on this part for a while, the elements of the table are overlapping when there are too many words inside the td.

link to the specific page: [here](http://demo.themeum.com/html/eshopper/cart.html)

also if you will resize your browser you will notice the overlapping even if there are not that many words inside the description td.

For now i just tried using max-width to set the width but it still not a favorable result since there is still overlapping present.

is there anyway for me to get around this problem or solve it?

Also this is a responsive template.

the content of my description is like this:
Tired of all those bones while eating? then try our boneless chicken breast you can swallow it whole and no bones to worry about.

[image: image here]

Comment: Are you using `width` property on td element that contains description text?

Comment: @IvanJ yes i am, is that wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a width to `.cart_info table tr td`. For example:

```
.cart_info table tr td{
  width: 30%;
}
```

or if you just want to target the `.cart_description`

```
.cart_info table tr .cart_description{
  width: 30%;
}
```

I made up width: 30% just for testing purposes. You can specify whatever width that you want.